# Weekly Data show

Tags: vb.net

Please any one help me, I just making a micro finance type software, there was a problem I want to show every week data from access database to vb.net datagrid view but don't work my code,

I insert EntryDate Savings Entry Lable Date (lblSavingsEntryDate.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))

Here is my Code

```
Private Sub btnBalanceWeekly_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBalanceWeekly.Click

    Dim Sunday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((Today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday) * -1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Dim todate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Try
        Dim sqlstr1 As String
        sqlstr1 = "SELECT * FROM Receivedtbl WHERE  EntryDate BETWEEN '" + Sunday + "' And '" + todate + "'"
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr1, conn2)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("Receivedtbl")
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvBalanceSavings.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn2.Close()
        Me.BalanceTotalSeavings()
        Me.BalanceGrpReceived()
        Me.BalanceCusReceived()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Please Help... How can show data in every week.

Answer (score 1):

It's much more secure and safer way using `Parameters` (`DataAdapter` will convert in proper way `date`, `datetime` format in sql) instead converting `date` into `string`, especially because different date formats and avoiding sql injection.
Bellow is example with using `Parameters` in, let say, source format (in this case `date` data type) :

```
Private Sub btnBalanceWeekly_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBalanceWeekly.Click

    Dim Sunday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((Today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday) * -1)
    Dim todate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0)
    Try
        Dim sqlstr1 As String
        sqlstr1 = "SELECT * FROM Receivedtbl WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN @sunday AND @todate;"
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr1, conn2)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sunday", Sunday)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todate", todate)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("Receivedtbl")
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvBalanceSavings.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn2.Close()
        Me.BalanceTotalSeavings()
        Me.BalanceGrpReceived()
        Me.BalanceCusReceived()
    End Try
End Sub
```

By this way You don't have to worry about `date` format conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to compare a date (string date) as "dd/MM/yyyy" format and you have a big problem because your query will be like this in runtime :

> WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN '11/02/2018' And '12/02/2018'

Result : Tons of strings are between these dates

For example : '11/02/2018','11/03/2018','11/04/2018', even another year like '11/02/2019'

In string compare, early characters always compare first and they are more important in compare system (in this case your 4 chars for year have less priority than month and even day)

**Solution :**

Use this format for saving your date :

> .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")

So your code should be like this :

```
Private Sub btnBalanceWeekly_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBalanceWeekly.Click

    Dim Sunday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((Today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday) * -1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    Dim todate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    Try
        Dim sqlstr1 As String
        sqlstr1 = "SELECT * FROM Receivedtbl WHERE  EntryDate BETWEEN '" + Sunday + "' And '" + todate + "'"
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr1, conn2)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("Receivedtbl")
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvBalanceSavings.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn2.Close()
        Me.BalanceTotalSeavings()
        Me.BalanceGrpReceived()
        Me.BalanceCusReceived()
    End Try
End Sub
```

**But remember you need save your date string with this format too (old dates which already saved in your database)**

Comment: Thank you, But when I want data in next week how It Possible ? I want data between Sunday to Saturday in every week. Please help me and give me the code.

Comment: @SuvoGhosh I update my answer, Hope you fix your problem. let me know the result after you check this code

Comment: Thank you.. Don't Show any data.

Comment: Sir, Please Share which type data I insert in my access Database in date field??? Please help...

Comment: I write this answer depend on your type which is string with 10 length

Comment: Sorry, This code show only two date value like "22/02/2018" and "28/02/2018" don't show "23/02/2018", "24/02/2018", "25/02/2018", "26/02/2018", "27/02/2018" How to show all date "22/02/2018" to "28/02/2018". Please sir help me.

Answer (score 0):

First and forever turn on Option Strict. Compile Time errors - good, you can fix them. Runtime errors bad, you might not catch them. 
Add two DateTimePicker controls to your form and appropriate labels. There are all kinds of properties you can set if the defaults don't suit you.
The following code shows you how to use parameters with your SQL strings. This not only saves you headaches formating your string but could save your database from malicious input.

```
Private Sub GetSavings()
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Receivedtbl WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN @FromDate And @ToDate;"
        Dim FromDate As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
        Dim ToDate As Date = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date
        If FromDate >= ToDate Then
            MessageBox.Show("From date must be earlier than To date.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand With {
            .Connection = conn2,
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            .CommandText = strSQL}
        'Access cares not about the parameter names but about there order
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = FromDate
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = ToDate
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        'now continue with your .Fill code
End Sub
```

Comment: This code work properly when I compile my machine but when I am install this application to client machine that the code no work client don't show data, please help.. Please share how to Insert the date in my access database, I mean what  datatype I use to my database date field when I inserting data???

Comment: My first guess would be the connection string. Where is the db? Are all the permissions in order?  If you are sure you are connecting then maybe a version of .net, the os. Almost impossible to know without being there. All I could do is answer your initial question.